# How to assign a Value of the same key within different multi-dimensional associative arrays to a variable

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have this arrray:

```
Array( [memberemailaddress] => Array
        (
            [id] => memberemailaddress
            [tag] => {my:memberemailaddress}
            [label] => Memberemailaddress
            [callback] => memberemailaddress
        )

    [membertelephonenumber] => Array
        (
            [id] => membertelephonenumber
            [tag] => {my:membertelephonenumber}
            [label] => Membertelephonenumber
            [callback] => membertelephonenumber
        )

    [officename] => Array
        (
            [id] => officename
            [tag] => {my:officename}
            [label] => Officename
            [callback] => officename
        ))
```

basically, each one of theses arrays inside of Array() contains the same exact keys. I am trying to create a function for each of the 'callback' values, to replace foo below.

```
        public function foo()
    {

    return 'fooValue';
    }
```

Desired Output:

```
        public function $array[$key]['callback']()
    {

    return '$array2[$key]';
    }
```

This is $array2:

```
$data = array(

'@attributes' => array(
    'memberemailaddress' => 'member@gmail.com',
    'membertelephonenumber' => '555-1212',
    'officename' => 'Main Street',

    ));
```

Desired output...

```
    public function memberemailaddress()
    {

    return 'member@gmail.com';
    }
```

Attempt:

```
 $realKey = "";
foreach($array[$key] as $key) {    
    $realKey = $array[$key];

}
    public function ($realKey[$key]['callback'])() { 

return '$array2[$realKey]';
}
```

If theres an easier [to follow this](http://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/merge-tags/), please advise. All help appreciated.

Comment: what is your expected output finally?share in the same format as you shown your input array.

Comment: What funky syntax is this `public function ($realKey[$key]['callback'])()`? Could you explain **why** you want to do this? What you are trying to do is **very** unusual and probably a very bad idea.

Comment: I am trying to follow this: http://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/merge-tags/ callback is used for function.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
function getFoo(array $arr) {
    return $arr['callback'];
}
```

Comment: Needs to  fit in here: where public function foo() is http://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/merge-tags/

Comment: @user3147682 Is it what you wanted or not ? If not, what doesn't work ?